# How could I get the username of a wikipedia user, if I have his user ID?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Using wikipedia API or whatever.

I can only do it reversely, i.e. using username to query user ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can fetch the username based on the user id from Wikipedia's web API. You can use a [simple query to Wikipedia's public database](http://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/7235), though:

```
SELECT user_name FROM user
WHERE user_id = ?
```